# Diophantine equation Ion Cucurezeanu

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, diophantine-equations

a) Prove that any integer n greater that 1, the equation $x^{n}+2^{n} = y^{2}+2$

b) Solve the equation $x! + y!+z!= 2^{v!}$

What I tried on b): Assume $x \geq y \geq z$. If $z \geq 3,$ $3|LHS,$ contradiction. Also $2^{v!} = x! + y! + z! \geq 3,$ so $v>1$.

A a) I think I would have to use LHS too, but how?

Comment: There's something missing in part a).  What about that equation?

Comment: This equation a) is right, at least I think it's  Ion Cucurezeanu

Comment: But it's not a sentence.  What do you want to prove?  The equation has no solutions?  Infinitely many solutions?  Something else?  What are $x$ and $y$?  Integers?  Complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.- a) $x^{n}+2^{n} = y^{2}+2$ then $x$ and $y$ have same parity.We have
$$2(2^{n-1}-1)=y^2-x^n$$ In both cases of odds and even $RHS$ is divisible by $4$ but $LHS$ is not.

b) let $x\le y\le z$ and $x\gt2$ then $3$ divides $2^v$, absurde. it remains to see the cases
$$1+y!+z!=2^v\\2+y!+z!=2^v$$ The firs is not possible because odd=even and the second case is similarly discarded.

Comment: Case $1:$ $z=2$
$x! + y! = 2^{v!}-2$. $\mod 3$ gives $y=2$ and so $x! = 2^{v!}-4$. Now $v\geq 3$ and $x!$ is divisible by $4,$ but not by $8,$ which is not possible.

Case $2:$ $z=1$
$x! + y! = 2^{v!}-1$ and thus $y=1$ (otherwise the $LHS$ is even). Now $x! = 2^{v!}-2$ and $x!$ is divisible by $2,$ but not by $4$, so $x<4$. This gives us the solutions $(x, y, z, v) = (2, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 1, 3)$ and permutations.

Comment: I think it would be permutations of (2, 1, 1, 2) just

Comment: @Esposa Do Yoongi: Yes,there are simple solutions for simple exceptions but in general cases the problem is very easy really.